# regex replace preceding zeros with equal amount of space

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am searching for a regexp that replaces preceding zeros with equal amount of spaces in notepad++.

`^(0+)` gets all the zeros but how can i replace them with an equal amount of spaces?

```
00000000 
00000001 
00000072 
00000073 
00000070 
00001105 
00000176
```

should become

```
       0
       1 
      72 
      73 
      70 
    1105 
     176
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<![1-9])0(?=\d)
```

Then just replace with the space character

Comment: thx. i did not know look ahead and look behind operators until know.

Comment: you can try `(?<![1-9])0(?!$)` as well.